# Identities for the soft minimum/maximum

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, reference-request, convex-analysis

For a continuous, positive function $f \in C(X)$, consider the soft-minimum
$$
\min^\varepsilon_{x \in X} \left\{ f(x) \right\} := - \varepsilon \log \left ( \int_X \exp(-f(x) / \varepsilon) \mathrm{d}\mu(x)\right).
$$

For the usual infimum, various identities exist such as 
$$
\inf f+g \geq \inf f + g,
$$
$$
\sup f+g \leq \sup f + g,
$$
$0\leq f \leq g$: 
$$
\sup f \leq \sup g, \inf f \leq \inf g,
$$
$$
|\sup f - \sup g| \leq \sup |f - g|
$$
$$
|\inf f - \inf g| \leq \sup |f - g|
$$

I'm looking for a reference which shows these identities for the soft-minimum and maximum (in case they hold), or in case they don't hold characterize the "sharpness" in some sense.

Comment: The right-hand side of the defining equation does not depend on $x$. Is the soft-minimum a function of $\varepsilon$?